# Ansible how to check a file exists in buffer

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I have a role A which is fetching a file to buffer like below. Now I have another role B which has to copy the file to DB servers if the file exists in buffer. How an i check the file exists in the master buffer?

**Role A**

```
  - name: fetch the log to buffer from app servers
    fetch: src=/tmplogs/script.log dest=buffer/ flat=yes # To ./playbooks/buffer
```

**Role B**

```
- name: Copy log from buffer to db server
  block:
  - name: Check if log exists in buffer
    stat:  path=buffer/.log
    register: script_buffer

  - name: Copy log from buffer to db servers
    copy: src=buffer/script.log  dest=/opt/script.log
    when: script_buffer.stat.exists
```

I cant use stat here beacuse it runs on remote host. How to achieve this?

Comment: not sure what you are asking exactly but have you considered `delegate_to: localhost` to run that particular task on localhost (I believe you call this master?)

Comment: Can you just put `ignore_errors: yes` on the task?

Comment: Thanks Jbone, localhost works. Not sure how missed this simple one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but you need to run the `stat` module on your local host, rather than on the remote host:

```
  - name: Check if log exists in buffer
    delegate_to: localhost
    stat:
      path: buffer/.log
    register: script_buffer
```